# removing unnecessary code at compile time

Tags: c++, gcc

I use the CImg library to write plugins for an image-editing software I created.
The problem is that when I include CImg, size of the plugins explodes from 200kb up to 2Mb!
But in this particular case I only use 5% of CImg code!

So my question is: is there a way to remove unnecessary code at compile time, so the final executable is not bloated?

(I use Qt 4.8.0 and the latest CImg, Qt Creator and MacOS Lion).

Compile/Link flags:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
LIBS += -Wl --gc-sections

Comment: The QT libs alone are e few megabytes in size so i wouldn't worry too much about the executable size. On the other hand only because you just use 5% who guarantees that the functions you are calling are not using the other 95%? Are you static linking the lib with your software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling with full optimisations (or just `-Os` which is size optimisation) and stripping debug symbols with `strip -s`. That can take up a lot of space.

Also it could be that while *you* are only using 5% of the CImg code, the 5% you use is using the other 95% internally. Pretty much the best you can do is optimise and strip debug symbols.

Comment: `-Os` won't affect the linker, which is what brings in all the CImg code.

Answer (score 2):

The first and most obvious: have you stripped the debugging information? Try the command

```
strip -s <program>
```

Also, compiling with -Os may help a bit.

Comment: Here's what I catually use:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
LIBS += -Wl --gc-sections

Comment: And it's compiled in release mode ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), gcc can remove unused non-static functions via [dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) when -flto option is combined with either -fuse-linker-plugin or -fwhole-program option.

Clang also [supports link time optimization](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html), which can remove unused non-static function across linked files.